# My first full contact-less power meter doubts

Tags: measurement, energy, esp32, power-meter, non-contact

I need to measure power consumption of an industrial machine, it is supplied with 3-phase plus neutral connections, 220V per phase. They said there is a voltage stabilizator device between the power network and the machine inputs, so I thought to consider a fixed voltage of 220V and only measure the current with an current transformer. The measurement needs to be fully non-intrusive/invasive.

I don't need precision on this, if I can estimate the power consumption on each phase, that's ok.
There is heating power resistences to be measured inside the machine on one phase and also a monophasic motor on another. The other phase I don't know yet what it will be connected to it internally.

What's my idea to measure AC current? Currently I choose a 100A:50mA current transformer, its output goes to a resistence to convert to voltage, then the signal goes to a precision full wave rectifier, then I plan the measure its output with the ESP32 12bit ADC at around 10Ksamples/sec. ESP32 ADC voltage reference is 1.1V and I know that the conversion is not so much linear on it, if really required I will add external ADC with a good voltage reference.

[image]

[image]

At the output of the split core current transformer I suppose there will be a maximum of 50mA peak, so 50mA * 13.6R = 680mV. Also I though that in practice I will need to use a 150A:75mA CT in worst case. 75mA * 13.6R = 1020mV. That's why I did not increased the resistence value. My preference is an adaptive circuit that can work with single 3.3V supply.

How I would measure RMS current? For a period of 1 second, take 10.000 samples (each 100us), convert the ADC value of each measurement to current value in A, square them, summ all, divide by 10.000 and finally make a square root off all. Is there something wrong with this?

I did some research on web about contact-less AC voltage measurement, and it seems very difficult to me, some methods like capacitive coupling measurement.

I though to only measure RMS current and multiply by fixed 220V to obtain apparent power, due to the voltage stabilizator used on the machines. I think doing this, to estimate the power on the heating resistences it would be ok, because this kind of load is almost only resistive, and it should be considered that the machine do phase control on them to control the heating amount. I think there is very low or no phase difference between current and voltage on it (do these resistences have inductive properties like a wirewound one?), with a good power factor. The problem is to measure the monophasic motor, the current-voltage phases will be different, correct? A big doubt that I have is if it is possible, for the motor voltage supply, to correct the power factor of it using a capacitor, to make less difference on their phases, increasing power factor.

The final objective is to measure power consumption and estimate the costs to operate such machines. Main difficult is on how measure AC voltage without make contact with the wires.

What could I do?
Regards.

Comment: Have a look at http://openenergymeter.org where all of this had been solved already.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks. The correct link is openenergymonitor.org